# Perform database save after Response in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, httpresponse, laravel-5.1

I'd like to not hold up the client with a database save and so I'd like to do something like what is shown for [Laravel 4, see below](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events) but just on one specific controller.

```
App::shutdown(function($request, $response)
{
    // after response to client
    App\SearchLog::create($request->all());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName()
```

for checking which controller is performed in "App::shutdown".